# PHP | LDAP | Live search in AD

Tags: php, ajax, search, active-directory, ldap

I am using the live search function for my MySQL database data.
But to go directly to the source I do not want a file or db in between and I went directly to the Active Directory itself.

The searching is working but after you searched for something like username, it gives the correct output, the data resets after 2/3 seconds. So the input type text is still filled in but it's showing all the results.

Does anyone can help me with this or can optimize the code?

INDEX.PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Live Search</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <h2 align="center">Live Data Search Active Directory</h2><br />
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
                    <input type="text" name="search_text" id="search_text" placeholder="Search by Customer Details" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div id="result"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <br />

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    load_data();
    function load_data(query)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:"fetch.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{query:query},
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#result').html(data);
            }
        });
    }

    $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
        var search = $(this).val();
        if(search != '')
        {
            load_data(search);
        }
        else
        {
            load_data();            
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

My fetch.php file with all the links to AD. Ofcourse crendentials and server are filled in and binding is working.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
        <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
    </head>
</html>
<?php

$output = "";

$ldap_password = "<username>";
$ldap_username = "<password>";
$ldap_connection = ldap_connect("<ldapserver>");

if (FALSE === $ldap_connection){
    echo "Unable to connect to the ldap server";
}

ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die("Unable to set LDAP protocol version");
ldap_set_option($ldap_connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if (TRUE === ldap_bind($ldap_connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password))
{
    if (isset($_POST["query"]))
    {
        $search = $_POST["query"];
        $search_filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(|(sAMAccountName=*".$search.")(sAMAccountName=".$search."*)(l=*".$search."*)))";
    }
    else
    {
        $search_filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(|(sAMAccountName=*)))";
    }

    $output .= '<table id="customers"><tr><th>Username</th><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Office</th><th>Department</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Telephone</th><th>E-Mail Address</th></tr>';

    $ldap_base_dn = "OU=NL,DC=global,DC=com";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap_connection, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter);

    if (FALSE !== $result){
        $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap_connection, $result);

    //var_dump($entries);

    //For each account returned by the search
    for ($x=0; $x<$entries["count"]; $x++){

        //Windows Username
        $LDAP_samaccountname = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["samaccountname"][0])) {
        $LDAP_samaccountname = $entries[$x]["samaccountname"][0];
        if ($LDAP_samaccountname == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_samaccountname= "";
        }
        } else {
        //#There is no samaccountname s0 assume this is an AD contact record so generate a unique username

        $LDAP_uSNCreated = $entries[$x]["usncreated"][0];
        $LDAP_samaccountname= "CONTACT_" . $LDAP_uSNCreated;
        }

        //Last Name
        $LDAP_LastName = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["sn"][0])) {
        $LDAP_LastName = $entries[$x]["sn"][0];
        if ($LDAP_LastName == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_LastName = "";
        }
        }

        //First Name
        $LDAP_FirstName = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["givenname"][0])) {
        $LDAP_FirstName = $entries[$x]["givenname"][0];
        if ($LDAP_FirstName == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_FirstName = "";
        }
        }

        //Company
        $LDAP_CompanyName = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["company"][0])) {
        $LDAP_CompanyName = $entries[$x]["company"][0];
        if ($LDAP_CompanyName == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_CompanyName = "";
        }
        }

        //Department
        $LDAP_Department = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["department"][0])) {
        $LDAP_Department = $entries[$x]["department"][0];
        if ($LDAP_Department == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_Department = "";
        }
        }

        //Office
        $LDAP_Office = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["l"][0])) {
        $LDAP_Office = $entries[$x]["l"][0];
        if ($LDAP_Office == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_Office = "";
        }
        }

        //Job Title
        $LDAP_JobTitle = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["title"][0])) {
        $LDAP_JobTitle = $entries[$x]["title"][0];
        if ($LDAP_JobTitle == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_JobTitle = "";
        }
        }

        //Mobile Number
        $LDAP_CellPhone = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["mobile"][0])) {
        $LDAP_CellPhone = $entries[$x]["mobile"][0];
        if ($LDAP_CellPhone == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_CellPhone = "";
        }
        }

        //Telephone Number
        $LDAP_DDI = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["telephonenumber"][0])) {
        $LDAP_DDI = $entries[$x]["telephonenumber"][0];
        if ($LDAP_DDI == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_DDI = "";
        }
        }

        //Email address
        $LDAP_InternetAddress = "";

        if (!empty($entries[$x]["mail"][0])) {
        $LDAP_InternetAddress = $entries[$x]["mail"][0]; 
        if ($LDAP_InternetAddress == "NULL"){
        $LDAP_InternetAddress = "";
        }
        }

        $output .= '<tr><td><strong>' . $LDAP_samaccountname .'</strong></td><td>' .$LDAP_LastName.'</td><td>'.$LDAP_FirstName.'</td><td>'.$LDAP_CompanyName.'</td><td>'.$LDAP_Office.'</td><td>'.$LDAP_Department.'</td><td>'.$LDAP_CellPhone.'</td><td>'.$LDAP_DDI.'</td><td>'.$LDAP_InternetAddress.'</td></tr>';


        } //END for loop
        echo $output;
        } //END FALSE !== $result
        echo("</table>"); //close the table     
} 
?>
```

The loop is to display multiple results.

[As you can see the result is good, but after 2/3 sec it resets and shows all data instead of the "sbx" value. (data is confidential so not shown, but it's corect)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x60mf.png)

Greets, Stef

Comment: The 'ready' event could be fired when fetching data, so in your `$(document).ready()` handler you can put a condition : `if ($('#result').is(':empty')){
  load_data();
}` to prevent reloading data after an actual search request occurs.

Comment: @EricLavault thank you for your answer Eric. Where should I put it exactly because if I set it inside the ```$(document).ready(function(){  }``` it's not working

Comment: At the very begining instead of the line `load_data();`.

Comment: The beginning is as followed now: ```$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($('#result').is(':empty'))
 {  
  load_data(); 
 }```
Unfortunately data is still refreshing after 2/3 sec...

Comment: There might be some other code chunks involved. Open your browser console and in the network tab check if there is any unwanted call to fetch.php (other than when you type in the search bar or in the document ready handler). Check that your ready handler is called only once, not after fetching data. Use `console.log()`and `debugger` for debugging javascript.

Comment: When I enter 3 letters: "sbx" it receives 4 POST's: https://gyazo.com/cd7e65978d7c49399c47b42df43687a9
The last POST resets the data

Comment: So we can see that this is actually the initial call to fetch.php (load_data() in ready handler) that is involved here, it takes more than 5 sec. to end. If you look at the timeline, the 1st call ends after the 2nd and 3d one, it takes too long to load all the users in your directory. You might have to omit the initial call, or use a cached version of the data to prevent such long response time.

Comment: Thanks Eric, do you also have an idea what I can do best in this situation? I understand what you're saying but I have no idea how I could solve this.

Comment: I guess you should go first without the initial loading (ie. blank resultset at page load).